# How do I make a prettierrc file that completely disables prettier?

Tags: prettier

I'm editing a repository that doesn't use [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier), but my editor (Emacs) loads `prettier-js-mode` based on file extension. So when saving a file I get a bunch of whitespace changes that I can't commit as it would polute the upstream repository.

My idea so far is to add a local `.prettierrc` file that disables Prettier, then add it to my `.git/config/exclude` file so upstream doesn't have to know about it.

But how do I craft such a file?

In my case I'd like to have a file in the project's root directory that would disable Prettier for the whole project, but I can also see how others might wish for a way to do the same thing for a subdirectory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about adding the `.prettierignore` with a `*` in it?

Comment: What about creating a PR to add prettier to that repository? ;)

Comment: @ManuelBieh That's what I usually do-I even created a CLI tool that let's me do it in a single command including formatting and githooks: https://github.com/capaj/be-pretty

Answer (score 0):

prettier-js-mode should have a config to only enable itself when it finds prettier config in the root or in package.json. The same as vscode and atom plugins do. If it doesn't have this feature it would be nice to open an issue or a PR.
The accepted answer is kinda hacky, but sure it will work too.